# Cara Pils Dextrine

Tags: steeping, mash, conversion

Want to use Cara Pils-Dextrine in my next brew to add body and aid in head retention. I have not made the jump to all grain yet, and I am doing a partial mash.  Will steeping/mini-mashing Cara Pils like a specialty grain work, or do I need to do a full mash to get my desired results?

Answer (score 3):

### Short Answer

Steeping CaraPils is fine.

### The Reasoning

One of the goals of mashing is [conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashing#Conversion), which breaks down starches present in grain to sugars that yeast can eat.  Some malts are converted in the *malting* process making it unnecessary to *mash* for conversion. The HomebrewTalk wiki lists "mash req'd" column on their [malts chart](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/wiki/index.php/Malts%5FChart) indicating which malts must be mashed to convert.

Comment: Light caramel malts, including carapils, are not fully converted during the stewing (mash-in-the-husk) process. Steeping anything under about 30L will add unconverted starches. Whether they will add _enough_ unconverted starches to cause problems is another matter, and many extract recipes take a "who really cares, go ahead and steep carapils" approach. But you're still adding starches.

Answer (score 0):

I think its important to point out the differences between steeping and mini/partial mashing.

You can steep cara-pils, but keep it to less than 5% of the grain bill as you'll probably add too much uncoverted starch.

However, if you really mean mash the carapils, then you can go whole hog and use what ever % you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can steep it or use dextrin (same thing).  It's the other white powder.  Cheers.